# Turtlebot forward/backward movement inverted in rviz

Tags: rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have been working with the "SLAM Map Building with TurtleBot" tutorial for a couple of days now. There is however a strange problem when moving the Turtlebot around; namely that is moves backwards in rviz when we are moving it forward and vica verse. Left and right movement seems to be acting normal, only forward and backward movement is inverted.

Does anyone happen to know why this could be happening?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32271/turtlebot-forward/backward-movement-inverted-in-rviz/) by [bootsman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2218/bootsman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AjayKumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/91678/ajaykumar/) on 2021-12-17**:
Hi, I'm facing the same issue, can you please suggest what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds to me as though your teleop code may have been changed thus inverting the drive parameters. What packages are you using to drive your turtlebot around? If you are using the turtlebot_teleop node your Up=Forward should read 1.0 and Down=backwards should read -1.0. I would use rostopic echo to figure out what your teleop is publishing. Also what version of ros are you using?

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2012-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have used turtlebot teleop mentioned in this [turtorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_teleop/Tutorials/Teleoperation) which works fine for me without any issues. I guess it says to use the buttons u i o; j k l; m , .; as the keys to control the robot. Please check if the topic it publishes is correct or not. I may be wrong but are you simulating the robot or using a real one. How does the real robot move when you give these commands.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1